# Download a file from mysql result which is on the web page

Tags: php, mysql, download

My problem is to download a File (any extension) by clicking the download icon, I have tried with Print statement but it will open a new window and displaying, a user can print the entire  web page , but i need to give them to download a single file from query.
Any idea ??

This is how my query is displaying , when a user click on the image it should be able to download

```
    doc_id  passport_no   photo            nic_copy         passport_copy
    200004  N8899999      1376630109.jpg   1376630110.jpg   1376630111.jpg
```

and this is my coding ..

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
$file = $_GET['file'];
if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file) && preg_match('/\.pdf$/',$file)) {
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
readfile($file);
}
} else {
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo "<h1>Error 404: File Not Found: <br /><em>$file</em></h1>";
}
?>
```

A download link

```
<a href="http://localhost/visa/view.php?file=example.pdf">Click here to download PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="view.php?file=<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>">Click here to download PDF</a>
this will be your view.php
<?php 
$f="upload/".$_REQUEST['file']; // upload is your destination folder where you  uploading you files
if(file_exists($f))
{
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($f));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($f));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($f);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @chirag ode this helped me solve my problem, i just made a change on my code

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP headers to tell the browser to save the file rather than display it.

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=whatever.ext');
header('Content-type: mime/type');
//echo file contents out here
```